# Why I cant update rows with PDO using prepare function?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an SQL **$query** like this;

```
UPDATE `tags` SET `tags.name` = :name, 
                  `tags.slug` = :slug,
                  `tags.date_published` = :date_published,
                  `tags.meta_title` = :meta_title,
                  `tags.meta_description` = :meta_description,
                  `tags.meta_keywords` = :meta_keywords
 WHERE `tags.id` = :id
```

And my **$values** array;

```
Array
(
    [:name] => iphone
    [:slug] => iphone
    [:date_published] => 2016-03-27
    [:meta_title] => iphone Yazıları
    [:meta_description] => iphone hakkında son gelişmeler ve faydalı bilgiler.
    [:meta_keywords] => iphone yazıları, iphone hakkında bilgiler, iphone haberleri
    [:id] => 24
)
```

I'm trying to update one row with PDO's prepare function;

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare($query);
$sth->execute($values);
echo "affected rows: ".$sth->rowCount(); // prints 0
return $sth->rowCount() ? true : false;
```

And I get no errors but rows are not affected after execute the query. Where is my mistake?

[mysql tags table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voRkP.png)

*edit:*
I'm creating values array like this;

```
$params = array(
    "id", "name", "slug", "date_published",
    "meta_title", "meta_description", "meta_keywords");

$values = array();

foreach ($params as $key) {
    @$values[$key] = $_POST[$key];
}
```

And this is how I create the query;

```
$query = "UPDATE `$table` SET";
$values = array();

/* Add field names and placeholders to query. */
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
    $query .= " `{$table}.{$key}` = :" . $key . ",";
    $values[":" . $key] = $value;
}

/* Remove last comma. */
$query = substr($query, 0, -1);

/* Build where condition. */
if ($cond) {
    $query .= " WHERE ";
    foreach ($cond as $key => $value) {
        $query .= " `{$table}.{$key}` = :" . $key . ",";
        $values[":" . $key] = $value;
    }
    /* Remove last comma. */
    $query = substr($query, 0, -1);
}
```

Comment: your array looks strange. can you show your PHP code where you create this array?

Comment: It looks like you are using phpMyAdmin.  Have you confirmed (in phpMyAdmin) that the rows are indeed not being affected?  That will help you determine whether the problem is with your query, or with `rowCount()`.

Comment: If you are updating to the same data, then there is no update heppens and thus row count is 0.

Comment: @low_rents I added how i create the array.

Comment: @alexw Yes I checked rows, and they're not being affected. :(

Comment: @YourCommonSense No, I checked it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're escaping the column names incorrectly. For example, the back ticks should not enclose the whole of `tags.name`, but rather the table and column names separately:

```
`tags`.`name`
```

Checking the output of [PDO::errorInfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) confirms this (emulated prepares must be set to `false` in order to see this, however).

General notes:

- You don't need to specify the colon prefix for the keys of the array being bound (likewise when explicitly binding columns via [bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [bindValue()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)).
- You should avoid using back ticks in your PDO queries. They're a MySQL-specific feature, and PDO is not a SQL abstraction layer (thereby preventing one of the major benefits of PDO - portability).

Comment: Lots of thanks. :)
But when I set the emulated prepares to false, I can't use setFetchMode function for FETCH_CLASS why I cant?

Comment: This is not a limitation that I am aware of. I suggest you open another question outlining your new problem with example code, since the comments section isn't a practical place to solve this.